# elasticsearch completion suggester produce duplicate results

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, search-suggestion

I am using elasticsearch completion suggester thesedays, and got some problem that it always produce similar results.

Say I search with the following statement:

```
    "my_suggestion": {
>         "text": "ni",
>         "completion": {
>             "field": "my_name_for_sug"
>         }
>     }
```

And get the following results:

```
 "my_suggestion" : [ {
    "text" : "ni",
    "offset" : 0,
    "length" : 2,
    "options" : [ {
      "text" : "Nine West",
      "score" : 329.0
    }, {
      "text" : "Nine West ",
      "score" : 329.0
    }, {
      "text" : "Nike",
      "score" : 295.0
    }, {
      "text" : "NINE WEST",
      "score" : 168.0
    }, {
      "text" : "NINE WEST ",
      "score" : 168.0
    } ]
  } ],
```

So the question is how can I merge or aggregate the same results like "NINE WEST" and "NINE WEST ".

the mapping is:

```
    "my_name_for_sug": {
         "type": "completion"
        ,"analyzer": "ik_max_word"
        ,"search_analyzer": "ik_max_word"
        ,"payloads": true
        ,"preserve_separators": false  
    }
```

where *ik_max_word* is an chinese-specific analyzer, and it can do the standard analyzer's job.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Suggesters automatically de-duplicate same output (at least till 2.x). I haven't tried out 5.x yet, and there's some changes in suggesters there.
The problem seems to be your index analyzer, which is indexing your documents so that:

`"text" : "Nine West",
"text" : "Nine West ",
"text" : "NINE WEST",
"text" : "NINE WEST ",`

aren't exactly the same. You need to index them using an analyzer which lowercases the tokens, and strips extra spaces etc.
Once you do that, you should get de-duplicated output for suggestions, like you want.